# VBA: Runtime error 1004 using Solver

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, and have some trouble with using the Solver in a macro. I'm assigning a macro to a command button in Excel, and they calculate everything perfectly, but an ugly error shows up as well at the end ("Runtime error 1004, method calculation of object _application failed").

```
Sub serieus1()
'
' serieus1 Macro
'  

'
    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$R$15", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$18", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$B$3"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$L$19", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$L$15:$Q$15", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `SetCell:="$L$19"` to `SetCell:=Range("$L$19")`.  Also, try adding `SolverFinish` after `SolverSolve`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error in my Solver macro.

I tried some of the things mentioned in several Excel forums. As the comment suggests, I did add `SolverFinish`, and also wrapped all my `SetCells` to of `Range` type. I also saved the file and exited out of Excel.

That did the trick and the pop-up error vanished for me when I got back in.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this runtime error using Solver through the GUI, after I had been running some `SolverOk`'s in VBA. I came across a post on MSDN, ["Excel 2010 and Solver Issue,"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/59be3b9e-1f98-4206-a776-16208d99c6eb/excel-2010-and-solver-issue?forum=exceldev) and it recommended adding a `SolverReset` before you run your `SolverOk`. I ran `SolverReset` in the Immediate Window, and that got rid of the runtime error.

Previously I didn't have `SolverFinish` as Ram Narasimhan recommended, and if I had, that might have prevented the error in the first place, but that's just conjecture.

Comment: SolverReset solved my problem, while SolverFinish had not helped/sufficed.