# SolverOptions: How to find the parameter position (AssumeNonNeg)?

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I have been trying to run a VBA code with Solver problem without manually ticking the box in the `References` section of the `Tools` category on VB Editor. In order to do so, I will have to add `Application.Run` to the lines where I have a Solver function. The following is my code when I run the macro manually:

```
SolverOK SetCell:=Cells(LR + 1, 10), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$N$4:$Q$4"
SolverSolve True
```

And this has been converted to:

```
 Application.Run "SolverOK", "Cells(LR + 1, 10)", 3, "0", "$N$4:$Q$4"
 Application.Run "SolverOptions", 0, 0, 0.000001, 0.0001, False, False, False, 1
 Application.Run "SolverOptions", 100, 0, 0.075, False, True, 0, 0, 1, False, 30
 Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
```

But the code is still missing the `AssumeNonNeg` parameter for some reason. I want the solution to include negatives and making it equal to `False`. No dice ...

Here is the macro that I recorded manually:

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$59", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$Q$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.000001, Convergence:= _
        0.0001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
    SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, Multistart _
        :=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
        IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
    SolverSolve
```

Cannot figure out what exactly am I doing wrong. Thank you for taking a look at my question.

I have Windows 10, MS Office 2013 and the files are MS Excel 97-2003.

**Update:**

```
Application.Run "SolverOK", "Cells(LR + 1, 10)", 3, "0", "$N$4:$Q$4", 1, "GRG Nonlinear"
Application.Run "SolverOptions", 0, 0, 0.000001, False, False, 1, 1, 1, 1, True, 0.0001, False, 100, 0, False, True, 0.075, 0, 0, False, 30

Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
```

**Update2:**

Tried copying @Peh's code exactly. It did work for a single file. However, when I run it for other similar files via shell (using VBS), I am getting `Run-time error 1004: cannot run the macro 'solverOK'`. Searching the web gave the following link -- [VBA: Runtime error 1004 using Solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968981/vba-runtime-error-1004-using-solver)

Included `Application.Run "SolverReset", True` at the beginning and got the same error `Run-time error 1004: cannot run the macro 'solverReset. The macro may not be available in this workbook...'`

Comment: The issue in Update2 might be that the Solver add-in is not activated in Excel. **You cannot run any solver actions without a active Solver add-in** (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196600(v=office.14)?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). Therefore make sure the Solver add-in is active before you run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue probably is that

```
SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.000001, Convergence:= _
    0.0001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, Multistart _
    :=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
    IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
```

is not the same as

```
Application.Run "SolverOptions", 0, 0, 0.000001, 0.0001, False, False, False, 1
Application.Run "SolverOptions", 100, 0, 0.075, False, True, 0, 0, 1, False, 30
```

#### Why is this so?

In the first case you specify each parameter by it's name (eg `MaxTime:=0`). Therefore it doesn't matter in which order these parameters are.

But in the second case you cannot specify the parameters by name, so you have to specify them by their order. Therefore (according to the documentation of the the [SolverOptions Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/solveroptions-function)) the order of the parameters is always the same `MaxTime, Iterations, Precision, …`. If you now call the `SolverOptions` function twice you call them with the same parameters but different values.

Here you need to submit all parameters (in their correct order) in **one single** function call:

```
SolverOptions(MaxTime, Iterations, Precision, AssumeLinear, StepThru, Estimates, Derivatives, SearchOption, IntTolerance, Scaling, Convergence, AssumeNonNeg, PopulationSize, RandomSeed, MultiStart, RequireBounds, MutationRate, MaxSubproblems, MaxIntegerSols, SolveWithout, MaxTimeNoImp)
```

in your case

```
Application.Run "SolverOptions", MaxTime, Iterations, Precision, AssumeLinear, StepThru, Estimates, Derivatives, SearchOption, IntTolerance, Scaling, Convergence, AssumeNonNeg, PopulationSize, RandomSeed, MultiStart, RequireBounds, MutationRate, MaxSubproblems, MaxIntegerSols, SolveWithout, MaxTimeNoImp
'instead of the parameter names put in your values:
Application.Run "SolverOptions", 0, 0, 0.000001, False, False, 1, 1, 1, 1, True, 0.0001, True, 100, 0, False, True, 0.075, 0, 0, False, 30
'I replaced the missing parameter values with their default due to the documentation.
'Note that the values are re-ordered due to the correct parameter order
```

You need to set a value for **every** parameter in this list if you need them or not, you cannot omit one, otherwise the order gets disordered.

---

The same issue in `SolverOK`

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$59", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$Q$4", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```

is not the same as

```
Application.Run "SolverOK", "Cells(LR + 1, 10)", 3, "0", "$N$4:$Q$4"
```

especially when you surround that `"Cells(LR + 1, 10)"` by `""` it is a string and does not get evaluated as VBA code as expected.

According to the documentation of the [SolverOk Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/solverok-function) the order of the parameters is

```
SolverOk(SetCell, MaxMinVal, ValueOf, ByChange, Engine, EngineDesc)
```

and this should result in something like:

```
Application.Run "SolverOK", Cells(LR + 1, 10), 3, 0, "$N$4:$Q$4", 1, "GRG Nonlinear"
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, +1. According to the given list, `AssumeNonNeg` is the 12th parameter. I have set it to `False` and re-ran the code... Still no change... Only positive numbers are reported as solution.

Comment: Obviously you need to do the same with the `SolverOK` function. See my edit above. If this doesn't solve your question please edit your original question and add the code you actually use at the end of your question.

Comment: Hmmm, still didn't work. I'm updating the body of my question to show the current state of the code...

Comment: because you did not copy my code **exactly**, I explained why surrounding `"Cells(LR + 1, 10)"` by `""` dosn't make sense but you still have them. Also `"0"` is a string not a number `0`. Make sure to copy my code **exactly**

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote and ... seems like it opened up a different set of problems. Updated my question with Update2