# Run-time error 1004: cannot run the macro 'Solver[InsertFuction]'

Tags: vba, excel, shell

Basically, this issues arises from this topic: [SolverOptions: How to find the parameter position (AssumeNonNeg)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535436/solveroptions-how-to-find-the-parameter-position-assumenonneg)

When I open a file and import the `.bas` file and run it, everything works fine. However, when I try to apply the same procedure for all similar files using shell via VB script, I am getting the following error:

> Run-time error 1004: cannot run the macro 'SolverReset'. The macro may
>   not be available in this workbook

I initially tried without `SolverReset` and in that case I got an error saying

> Run-time error 1004: cannot run the macro 'Solver' The macro may not be available in this workbook.

It looks like as if Excel is not activating Solver add-in? What might be the problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a hunch, but what if you turn on "Trust access to the VBA project object model" in Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Macro Settings?

Comment: Its already enabled for all macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials the following worked for me:

in front of each `Solver` function (eg. `SolverReset`, `SolverOptions`, etc.) I put `Solver.xlam!` and ran the code. It didn't work but gave a warning that there was no `Solver.XLAM` in the directory. So I simply went to the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library\SOLVER` and copied both `Solver.XLAM` and `Solver32.DLL` to the directory. That was it!

Hope someone finds this useful!